# Choose current annotation

Tags: ios, dictionary

I receive a list of coordinates and insert it on the map. Then I got new coordinates and I want to move my pins with that code:

```
            [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
             [oldCoordinate setCoordinate:newCoordinate.coordinate];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         }];
```

I loop with that code with every new coordinate but I can not move it because I can not control it. If I use array I got, for example

```
 [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

And I recieve array with that I will work. How can I take find current annotation on map ? (annotation that already on the map, and which new coordinates I have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current annotations on the map you could loop like this:

```
MKMapView * map = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

for (MKPointAnnotation * annotation in [map annotations])
{
    //Change annotation coordinate to new coordinate
}
```